# How to create and populate a PostgreSQL table from CSV automatically?

Tags: postgresql, migration, csv

I am new to database management and we are using PostgreSQL. All I need to do is to migrate CSV files (corresponding to around 200 tables) to our database. Manually creating tables for every CSVfile is a bit tiresome, so please help me out. Is there any way not only to import data, but also to generate tables from CSV files?

Answer (score 6):

You might look at [PgFutter](https://github.com/lukasmartinelli/pgfutter) to help you out. It sounds like it would fit your use case well, because it creates tables for CSV formatted data based on the header line, and then loads the data into the tables.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34882452/26510) to a similar question on Stack Overflow gives more details on how to use PgFutter

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I wrote a script that can populate the table from CSV.

This is it:

```bash
DATADIR='data'                      # this directory name


PREFIX='jobd'
DBNAME='divacsv'

function createSchema {
    COLUMNS=`head -n 1 $1 | 
        awk -F, '{for(i=1; i<=NF; i++){out=out $i" text, ";} print out;}' | 
        sed 's/ text, $/MYEXTRA text/' | 
        sed 's/"//g'`
    CMD_CREATE="psql $DBNAME -c \"CREATE TABLE $2 ($COLUMNS);\""

    echo $CMD_CREATE
    sh -c "$CMD_CREATE"

    CMD_COPY="psql divacsv  -c \"COPY $2 FROM '"`pwd`"/$1' DELIMITER ',' CSV;\""
    echo $CMD_COPY
    sh -c "$CMD_COPY"
}

for file in $DATADIR/*.csv; do
    table=$PREFIX"_"`echo $file | sed 's/.*\///' | sed 's/.csv//' `
    createSchema "$file" $table
done
```

Comment: What is 'MYEXTRA' doing there?  Also, it looks like you are inserting the header into the table, too.  I think you need the `HEADER` option to `COPY`, too.  Furthermore, instead of the `sed` magic for removing the filename extensions, you could use `basename`.

Answer (score 0):

There's some ways to workaround this issue.
You can find some scripts around the internet which will do what you're looking for, but the best way I know is using this [Data Mover Project](https://github.com/vitoravancini/spark-data-mover).
Besides, it's already published to docker as techindicium/spark-datamover:v0.1.
You can call it from the command line:

`docker run --network host techindicium/spark-datamover:v0.1 -s /home/path/your_file.csv --filetype csv --destination "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:PORT/DATABASE?user=USERNAME&password=PASSWD" --destination-table MY_DEST_TABL`E

Answer (score 0):

`cvssql` from [csvkit](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) does the same. It analyses the data, so proper date fields will end up as date field, integer to integer etc. And you can choose to what type of db flavour: firebird, mssql, mysql, oracle, postgresql, sqlite & sybase.

As example the below command analysis the csv file and imports it into postgresql:

```
csvsql --tabs --quoting 3 --no-doublequote --escapechar \\ --skipinitialspace --db postgresql+psycopg2://@localhost/[DATABASENAME] --insert --create-if-not-exists --verbose --overwrite [CSV FILENAME]
```

with bash you can create a loop over all csv files and execute the csvsql command.